# Is it okay to say 'margin of survival'?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, terminology, word-usage, technical

I read a sentence 'Most animals lived very close to the margin of survival.' And the writer wanted to say:

> 'Most animals lived in conditions that were hard to survive.'

I wonder whether his sentence is awkward or not.

Comment: It's not awkward to me.  I'm a native speaker of American English. Think of the "margin" of a piece of paper, a narrow area running adjacent to the edge. That is "close to the edge, nearly off the edge". In your quote's metaphor, the edge is non-survival. Death. These animals were surviving, but were close to the edge (of death). Surviving, but barely.

Comment: The expression is generally used in financial contexts: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=margin+of+survival&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmargin%20of%20survival%3B%2Cc0 - here is an example in a context similar to yours: “ *The well- rooted image of Iceland's premodern human ecology is of a population struggling to survive in an inhospitable environment, pursuing European-style farming too near the Arctic and some highly active volcanoes, **always on the margin of survival.”***

Comment: Google Books claims over 90 written instances of [*live at the margin of survival*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22live+at+the+margin+of+survival%22) (and about the same for *live **on** the margin of survival*).

Comment: Pleases don't close the question. It is about a technical usage within the science of Ecology and Anthropology.

Comment: See page 408, top para of second column [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/38111785/098_Modern_Food_Technology.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A&Expires=1516382599&Signature=a%2BLYB%2FByldnupPIrcgEpsTOyORk%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DModern_Food_Technology_Industrializing_N.pdf#page=118) for an extended example with definitions.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness! I'm so happy with getting your answers which are really helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: It’s perfectly parallel to the similar (but [much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=margin+of+survival%2Cmargin+of+victory)) phrase, “margin of victory”, which means the difference between victory and defeat.  So, analogously, “margin of survival” is the difference between survival and death.